# Qual a lógica do for i 'in' em python

Tags: python, for

Eu gostaria de saber a lógica do `for i in vogais`, como no exemplo.

Dúvida, ele carrega a palavra digitada toda em uma lista na memória e já ordena conforme a nossa classificação,ou ele lê carácter por carácter?

Por exemplo, se digitar: "`alguma coisa aqui`", usando o *debug* Pycharm, ele já sabe a quantidade de letras `a`, por exemplo.

```
def contaVogais(caracteres):
  caracteres = caracteres.upper()
  result = 0
  vogais = 'AEIOU'

  for i in vogais:
      result += caracteres.count(i)
  return result
```

Comment: O `for` do Python realiza um laço que outras linguagens chamam de `foreach` (para cada). Dado uma sequência de elementos, para cada elemento dentro da sequência, faça "códigos".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `for x in variavel` é a mesma coisa do `foreach` das outras linguagens.

> Dúvida, ele carrega a palavra digitada toda em uma lista na memória e
>   já ordena conforme a nossa classificação,ou ele lê carácter por
>   carácter?

Não, ele não ordena no `for`, depende do tipo de dado, no seu exemplo você tem uma variável do tipo string, então quando você usa o sintaxe `for i in vogais` ele apenas está rodando um loop em cada letra da string.

> Por exemplo, se digitar: "alguma coisa aqui", usando o debug pycharm,
>   ele já sabe a quantidade de letras a, por exemplo.

Isso acontece porque você está usando o método `count` dentro do loop para contar quantas vezes um caractere aparece na string `caracteres.count(i)` onde o `i`representa a letra que você quer saber quantas vezes tem ocorrência.

Answer (score 1):

Neste caso não tem digitação alguma, mas pode ter em outra parte.

O `for` é uma laço controlado internamente, ele sabe onde começar (0) e onde acabar (o tamanho da coleção de dados).

Uma *string* em Python é uma coleção de caracteres sendo que antes de todos eles tem a quantidade de caracteres, então é fácil para o laço saber quando parar. É uma estrutura de dados completa. Não tem mágica.

O `count()` é uma das formas de pegar a quantidade de caracteres, mas aí ele tem que varrer toda a *string* toda vez. Este código é quadrático.

Comment: O count() é uma das formas de pegar essa quantidade de caracteres. Neste caso está executando dois laços (um deles está dentro do upper()), e isto não é eficiente. Na verdade todo o código não deveria ser assim.

Qual seria a forma mais eficiente, no meu exemplo?

Comment: @ElcyPintoAnjos eu tirei essa parte porque depois eu vi que tem uma diferença que faz necessário.