# Qual a diferença entre o operador IN e ==?

Tags: python, operadores

Eu gostaria de saber qual a diferença entro o operador `IN` e o `==` no Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"in" significa "esta contido" ou seja, pode se usar para verificar se um valor esta contido dentro de um conjunto de valores.
Exemplo:

lista = ['bola', 10, 'sapato', 'doce']
if('sapato' in lista):
    print('Bola esta contida em lista')

Já o "==" significa igual, e pode ser usado para verificar se um valor é igual a outro.
Exemplo:

nome = 'Paulo'
if(nome=='Paulo):
       print('O nome é realmente Paulo')

Desculpe a falta de indentação no código, sou novo no site.

Comment: Ótima Resposta.

Answer (score 5):

O `in` é um operador que esconde muita complexidade. Ele resultará em verdadeiro se o primeiro operado estiver contido no segundo operando, que pode ser uma lista qualquer, inclusive uma *string*.

```
print("b" in "abc")
print("b" == "abc")
print("abc" in "abc")
print("abc" == "abc")
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/7043mk). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/InEqualpy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Operator/InEqual.py).

Ele seria semanticamente equivalente a algo assim:

```
for char in "abc"
    if "b" == char
        return true
return false
```

[O `in` também é usado como construção do de um laço](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/279755/101).

Comment: O Operador IN Funciona com Inteiros ?

Comment: Em uma lista de inteiros, sim.

Comment: Obrigado◕‿◕ ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Answer (score 3):

Basicamente o `in` é, por exemplo, *A contido em B*, ou seja, existe um elemento C em B tal que A = C é verdadeiro.

Já no `==`, é, por exemplo, uma comparação, que se *A for igual a B* será verdadeiro.

Comment: Pode ser também =D

Answer (score -3):

O IN seria um tipo de lista, certo?

Exemplo:

select * from cliente c where c.codigo in (1,5,10)

Vai trazer somente os clientes que possuam os codigos iguais a regra definida em IN.

Já o == varia de linguagem, no dart por exemplo:

'==' - Utilizamos quando vamos verificar se uma variável é igual a outra.